# Extjs JSON reading from a file

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, extjs

For a project i am developing with Extjs(a javascript framework)
Because i have to understand communication between several layers of a system i build  an simple system of my own.

PostgreSQL is used as a database. PHP gets this data and stores in in a json file, named pg.json.

Now i cant seem to load the data from that already existing json file in a view in extjs. I tried multiple sources butt al where writing a json file themselfs. I already have a file(and it has to be done this way) and don't know how to load it. Im stuck. Please help!

Regards

Comment: Please don't forget to add code snippets, point out where you are stuck, and what you are trying, which tutorial you are following and other relevant information. `Please help!` is no relevant information.

Comment: You want to read a json file into a store?

Comment: I dont want to put all of my application code here, its just this question im stuck with. I want to read contents(an array that looks like this:[["1","Jeroen","SE"],["2","Jonathan","SE"],["4","Bram","hijs aardig"],["4","Bram","hijs aardig"],["10","Jonathan","hijs moe"],["10","Jeroen","test."],["10","Jeroen","test.php"]] i want that to load in a grid/tree panel but i dont know how to convert that json file to something readable and im stuck forever now;)

Answer (score 0):

The different Components in ExtJS (like `Ext.grid.Panel` or `Ext.tree.Panel`) have to get a `Ext.data.Store` attached. In a Store you can define proxies and readers that describe, how and where to retrieve data from, JSON is one example.

Have a look at:

- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel (config > store)
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel (config > store)
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

Comment: The only problem with this is that i dont understand how it the file is read. Does it need a array reader of a json reader?(or both?)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your json file is located at "/data/example.json" (relative path). You can store your json file data in store like below and then this store can be referenced in grid.

```
var user = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'user',
        model: 'User',
        autoLoad: 'true',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/data/example.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'blah'
            }
        }
    });
```